# Save mediaplayer state between activiites

Tags: java, android

I have a mediaplayer in my settings activity which plays a song when the toggle button is turned on. It works fine and when the activity is changed, the music continues to play which is what I want. The problem is, when I go back to the settings activity again, the toggle button is set to off and once clicked it starts a new media player which plays alongside the current one. Is there anyway for it to remember that the original media player is turned on?

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
public MediaPlayer mp = null;
private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
private AudioManager audioManager = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    initControls();


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (mp == null) {
                int song = getResources().getIdentifier(text, "raw", "com.example.dan14.memorygame");
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Settings.this, song);
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.stop();
                mp = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my idea your code should work fine at least most of the time.

Try 
`public static MediaPlayer mp = null;`

Update:
Normally when inter-activity property is needed such as music playing, you should try **Service**, one important Android feature. At least you should get know of it and decide what to do. Here's a comprehensive tutorial from Google. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: Thank you!! That works but I just gotta save the state of the button now cause it reverses when I relaunch the second activity. for example I fI click play and then change activity the music stays on which is fine but once I go back into settings activity the button is set to off but once clicked it says on but stops the music!

Comment: @Haldamir After `Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);`, change your button state according to if `mp == null`.

Comment: Thank You! I just set the button state using onPause and onResume :)

Answer (score 0):

Move the **Button** out of the `onCreate` and  place it as an Activity Member.